# Installing WP on localhost

Tags: local-installation

This is maybe a beginner question, but as [Codex Installing WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) says, I use to install WP on the server directly and then I do the changes on-line, instead of begin installing on my localhost and do the changes there.

However, I'm guessing this is not a good option. Could anyone confirm me that I should begin installing WP on my localhost?

So instead of `http://example.com/wp-admin/install.php`, I should go to `http://localhost/example/wp-admin/install.php`

Comment: Why not a simple [**googling**](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Install+wordpress+on+localhost) answer you? There are plenty of blogs explaining that in details.

Comment: I wonder why it's not explained on WP official site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving Wordpress from live to local server](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34031/moving-wordpress-from-live-to-local-server)

Comment: It actually [**has**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Installing_WordPress_on_your_own_Computer)

Comment: Installing WordPress locally is exactly the same as installing it on any other server, once you get the server itself setup. A server is a server. You should give your local server a static (local) IP and use that rather than use "localhost" though, if you need to access from multiple computers

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should only configure WP for localhost if you have physical possession of the computer/server.  You cannot access localhost of a remote computer.  Well there are tricks that this is beyond the scope of this discussion.

**Edited to add** To install WP on localhost, after installing the WP files, go to:

```
http://localhost/
```

or if you installed WP in a sub-directory:

```
http://localhost/wordpress
```

Comment: When I say localhost I mean my own computer and not the real server